# HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Http post request failed

Tags: java, scala, http-post

I am trying to use [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/RANGER/REST+APIs+for+Policy+Management#RESTAPIsforPolicyManagement-Createrepository:) rest api to create an hdfs repository in apache ranger using scala/java code. In this we need to pass parameters in json form. Here is my code

```
def createReposity() {
    val httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient()
    val httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:6080/service/public/api/repository")
    httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    httpPost.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password),
      "UTF-8", false))
    val reqEntity = new StringEntity(getJson)
    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity)
    val response = httpclient.execute(httpPost)
    println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode())
  }

def getJson(): String = {
    var json = "{\"name\": \"hadoopd_hdfs\",\"description\": \"hdfs repository using curl\","
    json += "\"repositoryType\": \"hdfs\",\"config\": \"{"
    json += "\"username\": \"admin\","
    json += "\"password\": \"admin\","
    json += "\"fs.default.name\": \"hdfs://localhost:9000\","
    json += "\"hadoop.security.authorization\": \"true\","
    json += "\"hadoop.security.authentication\": \"simple\","
    json += "\"hadoop.security.auth_to_local\": \"\","
    json += "\"dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal\": \"\","
    json += "\"dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal\": \"\","
    json += "\"dfs.secondary.namenode.kerberos.principal\": \"\","
    json += "\"commonNameForCertificate\": \"\"}\","
    json += "\"isActive\": true}"
    json
  }
```

When I execute this code it gives the error code 404 not found. Please guide me what's going wrong?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like the HTTP post is failing because the endpoint it's connecting to isn't there. Could you check if that port's listening?  (In linux or windows: `netstat -a -n -o`)

Comment: yes this 6080 port is listening

Comment: Could you, in your favourite HTTP program (I like SoapUI, but other prefer browser extensions), try sending a POST to that URL and see what you get?  Make sure to add pre-emptive basic auth on your request too.

Comment: Hi hugh! I am not getting any help how to do this? Please guide me what to do. Get request works fine on this url to retrieve repository details

Comment: Ok, that suggests the API is up!  Next, could you check if port 9000 is listening too?

Comment: yes that port is listening too

Comment: I'm afraid the next thing I'd suggest is Wireshark.  Try capturing the network traffic, and filter for an HTTP 404: ` http.response.code == 404`.  This will tell you exactly which request is returning the error, and let you inspect what was sent.  https://wiki.wireshark.org/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Hi hugh! this curl command works fine
curl -i --header "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --user admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:6080/service/public/api/policy -d '{ "policyName":"hdt","resourceName":"/test","description":"curl","repositoryName":"hdfs-repo","repositoryType":"hdfs","permMapList":[{"userList":["mujadid"],"permList":["Read"]},{"groupList":["internal"],"permList":["Read"]}],"isEnabled":true,"isRecursive":true,"isAuditEnabled":true,"version":"1","replacePerm":false}'

How can i convert this command into java code?

Comment: Just to check: That curl command is to "create policy", whereas your java code is "create repository".  Is that what you're intending?  Does the equivalent curl command work for "create repository"?

Comment: yes that command also works here it is
curl -i --header "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --user admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:6080/service/public/api/repository -d '{"name":"hdv","description":"","repositoryType":"hdfs","config":"{\"username\":\"admin\",\"fs.default.name\":\"hdfs://localhost:9000\",\"hadoop.security.authentication\":\"simple\",\"hadoop.security.authorization\":\"false\",\"password\":\"*****\",\"hadoop.rpc.protection\":\"authentication\"}","isActive":true,"version":"1"}'

Comment: Ok, I can give you the Java equivalent, but it's nearly identical to your Scala.  Only other thing I can suggest is use netcat to listen to port 6080 (after shutting down Ranger, or just use a different port), and send the two requests.  Netcat will show you exactly what's being sent, so if one works and the other doesn't, the difference must be in there.  Trying this myself, the only differences I can see are the capitalization of "Content-Type", spaces after the colons in headers, an extra header "Connection: Keep-Alive" (from Java), and of course the user agents.

Comment: thanks Hugh ! I will be thankful to you. I appreciate your effort.